# Conditional expectation property as expectation of indicator functions

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I am reading the following statement:

If $Y ∈ m{F}$ (F-measurable) and

$\mathbb{E}(X1A) = \mathbb{E}(Y1A)$ for all $A$ in a $π$-system that contains $Ω$ and generates $F$,

then $Y = \mathbb{E}(X|F)$ a.s..

Does this simply follow directly from the fact that $\mathbb{E}(X1A)= \int_{A}Xd\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{E}(Y1A)= \int_{A}Yd\mathbb{P}$, which are equal by the definition of conditional expectation, or is there something more interesting going on here?

Answer (score 1):

The point is that if we have to check that $Y$ is indeed $\mathbb E\left(X\mid F\right)$, we have to check the equality $\mathbb{E}(X1A) = \mathbb{E}(Y1A)$ for all $A\in F$, which can be hard. There are case where the previous equality is easier to check for the elements of a $\pi$-system generating $F$.

For example, let $X$ be a random variable and let $\mathcal F_1$, $\mathcal F_2$ be two $\sigma$-algebras such that $\mathcal F_2$ is independent of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$ and $\mathcal F_1$. Then we can check that 
$$
\mathbb E\left(X\mid \sigma(\mathcal F_1,\mathcal F_2)\right)=\mathbb E\left(X\mid  \mathcal F_1  \right)
$$
by using the previous result with the $\pi$-system of elements of the for $F_1\cap F_2$, where $F_1\in\mathcal F_1$ and $F_2\in\mathcal F_2$.

Comment: Understood. But it would seem that the proof of the statement is trivial, correct?

Comment: A proof would rest on the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem because we have to go from the $\pi$-system to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by this $\pi$-system. So it is not completely trivial.